# Import external method in C# from DLL written in C with multiple output params

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, unmanaged, native-code

I have a DLL that I cannot change that is part of a larger system that I need to import into a C# wrapper, and I am having a tough time with the Marshaling on this one. The last 3 parameters are output parameters.

Declaration:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Retrieve(unsigned long ifnds, unsigned long ifnid, char *path, char *userName, long *fcount, char **fileList[], unsigned char *del);
```

C# Import

```
[DllImport(@"C:\temp\TestLibExsh\libexsh.dll")]
internal static extern int Retrieve(uint ifnds, uint ifnid, string path, string username, out int fcount, out string[] fileList, out byte del);
```

When I try to run I get the following error:

*Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'executable path'.
Additional Information: A call to PInvoke function 'TestLibExsh!TestLibExsh.Program::ExternalRetrieve' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.*

Some assumptions I made.

unsigned long in C++ = uint in c#.
long in C++ = int in C#.

Not sure what happens with Marshaling of the last unsigned char*, as it does not need to be a string, but a single output character. It is used to return a Boolean more or less. Needless to say, the output array of strings complicates matters a bit as well.

Comment: Possibly relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148856/using-p-invoke-correctly

Comment: It turns out this is answered by the link provided by Hans Passant. I was off track to assume that my problem was related to the parameters I was passing. The following URL answers the question correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968154/pinvokestackimbalance-while-using-static-extern-int-systemstring-str